# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with function argument/parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have the following method, which I want to run using WaitCallBack delegate (C# Thread-Pooling) technique:

```
public void ExportData(string data){
//Codes goes in here
}
```

how to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ExportData),object}`
in order to call this method??

Comment: The web is full of tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WaitCallback that this function expects takes an object state parameter. So you could do this:

```
string data = "some data";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => ExportData((string)state), data);
```

or update the signature of your method:

```
public void ExportData(object state)
{
    string data = (string)state;
    //Codes goes in here
}
```

and then:

```
string data = "some data";
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ExportData, data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- Declare the method with type `string` and cast
- Use a lambda expression instead, e.g.

  ```
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ignored => ExportData(value))
  ```

  where I assume `value` is a string variable in scope at the time. This will create a new delegate instance each time you go through this code, to capture `value`.
- A combination of the above:

  ```
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => ExportData((string) x), value)
  ```

  This will (potentially) reuse the same delegate instance on every call, as the value is passed via the normal `WaitCallback` instead of being captured by the delegate.

Additionally, you might want to consider using the rather more modern `Task` API unless you're targeting an old version of .NET. It's a generally more pleasant way of scheduling and managing tasks.